# Join Table to create composite Primary Key

Tags: android, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables student and categories. Student and category has ManyToMnay relationship.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "student")
 public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "student_id",nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "student_name")
private String name;


@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "student_has_subject",

        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_student_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_subject_id"))
private List<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<>()
```

}

**Subject.class**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "subject")
public class Subject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "subject_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "subject_name",nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subjects")
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

But when I execute this in IDE. student_has_subject Table created but without creating primary key.

```
mysql> describe workflow_services;
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| student_id  | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| subject_id  | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How could I make both forieng key as primary.

When I create this no primary key created.

How to create new table name **student_has_subject** with a**ll column as primary key**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferred way to map a ManyToMany is using a Set rather than a List - [ManytoMany](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Also using a Set will generate a PK in the join table